# Erro oracle ora-06550 pls-00103:

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho este código PL-SQL:

```
/*1. Criar um bloco PL/SQL anônimo para imprimir a tabuada abaixo:*/

DECLARE
  VN CONSTANT NUMBER(2) := 5;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..1O LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_(VN || ' X ' || i ||'='|| VN*i);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Mensagem de Erro**

> Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: linha 4, coluna 18: PLS-00103:
>   Encontrado o símbolo "O" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era
>   esperado:
>
> - & - + / at loop mod lembrete rem  ||
>     multiset O símbolo "*" foi substituído por "O" para continuar.
>
>   6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>           *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>           *Action:

**Estrutura da Tabela**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `1..1O` <- Não seria um **zero** ? Em vez de **O** ?

Comment: OPS...grato!!! ...dever ser o cansaço...vou dormir!